# How can I insert date formatted data from an Excel file into SQL without getting an error due to the column format?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have an problem. I am trying to inserted data from excel file into SQL, however I am getting an error because of one column of date format.
My column is like this:

[image]

When I trying to insert data, I got an error on this step because of that column.

[image]

I have no control on excel file and I do not have possibility to change the format on excel file.

It seems that the excel file is assuming the date format for some columns and another is string.

I change the format on source output to string but here I am not have change.

[image]

I tried to inserted the data excluding this column and it works very well.

With this column, fail.

I do not know what to do in order to solve this.

I do not know if it is possible to change the column format in excel using C# code.

I would like to insert that column without issues.
The format should be string.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots.  High level I would import into a stage table where all columns are NVARCHAR or VARCHAR  and then do your checks/formatting in a SQL SP

Comment: Excel data decisions is figured out using data sampling of the first X number of rows.  By default, X is 10 (I believe).  You can force your import to interpret all data coming in from excel to a string type.  There is some connection command out there that allows you to read all columns in as a string (nvarchar/varchar).  The problem with this is, you will need to scrub each column yourself.  GL